# Is it possible to hide wallet address with ZK proofs

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, zksnark, zero-knowledge, anonymity, zkevm

We are working with zk contracts on partisia blockchain, so out of curiosity I want to hide the senders address while sending a transaction.
Consider a case where we are minting NFTs anonymously, if the user who has to mint the nft has to do it by sending a transaction, their address would still be stored on chain. Contradicting the anonymity.
Could there be any way around?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is Partisia blockchain, but I assume it's EVM based, since you're on this forum asking about it.

Since it's an EVM, it has quite limited possibilities for privacy. Transactions always have a clear sender, for example.

If you do not want to modify the blockchain protocol itsels (which would be a huge undertaking), you can't hide stuff like transaction sender.

But that doesn't mean that you are fully out of luck. You can utilize some sort of indirect obfuscation, similar to Tornado Cash. So users send something to a common contract which then, after a delay, issues the real commands to mint an NFT. And then the NFTs are given to new fresh addresses controlled by the original senders.

So even without direct ZK privacy you can still use ZK to achieve something similar, even if it means a bit less user friendly approach.